# Is there a quote/saying in bible "Do not close the mouth of a bull which threshes the grain"?

Tags: verse-identification

I am wondering if there is a quote in Bible saying "Do not mask/close the mouth of a bull which threshes the grain"?  Meaning, let the animal have its food while it works . When it comes to human, pay well to the workers.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this site does not entertain verse search questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original verse is Deuteronomy 25:4:

> Do not muzzle an ox while it is treading out the grain.(NIV)

The verse is referenced twice in the New Testament where it is explicitly said to apply to workers and wages:

> For it is written in the Law of Moses: “Do not muzzle an ox while it is treading out the grain.” Is it about oxen that God is concerned? (1 Cor 9:9)
>
> For Scripture says, “Do not muzzle an ox while it is treading out the grain,” and “The worker deserves his wages.” (1 Tim 5:8)